# Minecraft 1.12.2 modded server: "problem occured"

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have a minecraft modded server on 1.12.2, and it works for the most part, but it gives me an error.

The minecraft server is
`forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2846-universal.jar`, and I'm on lubuntu, using openJDK 10.

I have these mods:

> GalacticraftCore-4.0.2.236, GalacticraftPlanets-4.0.2.236, MicdoodleCore-4.0.2.236, and hopperducts 1.5

My system is:

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
>
> Release:        19.04

I tried reinstalling it, and it worked to get mission libraries(some) and then this came up.

My code to run is:

```
java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2846-universal.jar
```

where "forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2846-universal.jar" is the run file(yes, spelled correctly).

I just expected it to run, but it gave me this error:

```
A problem occurred running the Server launcher.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:70)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
        ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2):

For posterity's sake, the issue is openjdk-10.  The server .jar file uses something or other that isn't supported by versions of java after 8, and throws this same error you saw, that I spent a while chasing down.  There's another relevant thread [here](https://github.com/FTBTeam/FTB-Sky-Adventures/issues/295).  Solution: remove openjdk-10 (or whatever version you're using that isn't 8) with

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-10
```

and make sure version 8 is installed with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/MinecraftPortCentral/Cauldron-Issues/issues/26) on GitHub. Basically, the issue may be something with the vannilla Minecraft server.jar. Try re-downloading it, and manually renaming it. If that doesn't fix, there was a comment in there about Linux. Check that out.
Sorry I'm not more help. I'm not a Java developer, and I have just barely used Linux. I used CentOS a bit on my Raspberry Pi, and I used Ubuntu in a virtual machine, but besides that I'm a Windows user.